# how to install new Theme for Ubuntu Customization

Tags: customization, custom-distributions, custom-installer, customizer

I am customizing the ubuntu 12.04 LTS edition for my project work and I want to install new GUI look or theme in customization.

How can I inbuilt a new theme for Distro and make it as default theme.